S3 access: gateway endpoint vs interface endpoint
We can have VPC gateway endpoint as well as interface endpoint for accessing S3.
Which one to use in what scenario?

Suggest you read the available AWS guidance here.

VPC Gateway Endpoints and Interface Endpoints are used for different use cases based on performance, security, and architectural needs when accessing S3.
Use VPC Gateway Endpoints when you want to achieve the following:

High Throughput and Low Latency: Ideal for scenarios requiring high-volume, low-latency access to S3, as they provide direct, scalable access.
Cost Efficiency: Preferred for large data transfers due to no additional data processing charges.
Simplicity: Easier to configure and manage for straightforward S3 access.

Examples being: Data lakes, large-scale data processing, and backup solutions benefit from Gateway Endpoints for efficient data movement.
Use VPC Interface Endpoints for:

Fine-Grained Security Control: Necessary for applications requiring detailed access control via security groups.
Cross-Region Access: Suitable for multi-region setups or accessing S3 across different VPCs.
PrivateLink Integration: Useful when integrating with other AWS services using PrivateLink for consistent security policies.

Use cases: Applications needing precise access management, secure cross-region data flow, and compliance with strict security policies use Interface Endpoints.
